# A question regarding Hermite polynomials and exponential operators $\exp[e^{x^2/2}p(\frac{d}{dx})e^{-x^2/2}]f(x)$

Tags: lie-algebras, operator-theory, fourier-transform, integral-transforms, hermite-polynomials

Is it possible to express $$\exp\left[\mathrm{e}^{x^2/2}p\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2}\right] f(x)$$ as an integral transform or something similar? $p(x)$ is a polynomial.
$$\exp\left[\mathrm{e}^{x^2/2}p\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2}\right]f(x) = \int k(x,t)f(t)\,dt.$$
By expanding the exponential, I get
$$\exp\left[\mathrm{e}^{x^2/2}p\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)e^{-x^2/2}\right] f(x) = f(x) + \mathrm{e}^{x^2/2}p\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2}f(x) + \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{e}^{x^2/2}p\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2} f(x) + \ldots,$$
which has operator coefficients similar to [Hermite polynomials](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitePolynomial.html).

Comment: Initially asked https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/776205/332828

Answer (score 1):

You can of course write
$$
k(x,t) = \exp \left[ e^{-t^2 /2} p\left( -\frac{d}{dt} \right) e^{t^2 /2} \right] \delta (x-t)
$$
Not clear whether that affords you any sort of simplification you may be possibly hoping for.

Comment: I would like to get ride of the operator. Not sure this solution helps.

Comment: Similar to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_transform

Comment: I'm somewhat pessimistic. In the case of the Weierstrass transform, the operator is sufficiently simple such that one can identify it with a shift operator (after some manipulations). Once you start to go to more complicated operators, closed-form expressions quickly become unattainable. Maybe for selected polynomials $p$, it's still possible, but a formula for general $p$  ... I don't know.

Comment: What about approximation?

Comment: @Mirar - depends on what your small parameters are. You've already written down something like a perturbative expansion for the case that $p$ has small coefficients. It's thinkable to generalize this to the case that only some of the coefficients can be regarded as small. If the other terms correspond to a sufficiently simple, tractable problem, you can resum those and are then left with the perturbative series in the small terms.